# Visiting a suburl directly without going through an anchor gives error in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm having issue with visiting a link directly without going through a route-href anchor. For example standing on a page and hitting refresh, or copy pasting a link in the browser window.

what works:

http://localhost:9000/boards

http://localhost:9000/cards

What doesn't work:

http://localhost:9000/boards/1

http://localhost:9000/boards/anysuburl

The error I get is:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/boards/scripts/vendor-bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

If I change the path to vendor-bundle from:

```
 <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
```

to:

```
 <script src="/scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
```

the vendor-bundle is resolved but I get the same error on app-bundle.js

How the router is setup:

```
      configureRouter(config, router) {
config.title = 'Aurelia';
config.options.pushState = true;
config.options.root = '/';
config.map([
  {
    route: ['', 'cards'],
    name: 'cards',
    moduleId: './pages/cards/cards',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Cards',
  },
  {
    route: ['boards'],
    name: 'boards',
    moduleId: './pages/boards/index',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Boards',
  },
  {
    route: ['boards/:id'],
    name: 'board',
    moduleId: './pages/boards/details',
    title: 'Board',
  }
```

I have tried '/pages', './pages' and 'pages' with the same result

Comment: Do you have a base tag defined? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: base tag as suggested fixed the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Great. I've added it as an answer

Comment: As I look at the roter documentation again http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/1 I can see that it is actually documented.. It's me who missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a base tag to your html, like this:

```
<base href="/">
```